# RecyclerView with EditText: Worng Keyboard for a split second

Tags: android

So I have this wierd behaviour with my EditText in my RecyclerView.

When I click on a Button, located in one Item of this RecyclerView, I get the Text from the EditText, store it in an Object and set the Text to some Data from another object.

The problem is, the EditText has the InputType "Number" and when I click on the Button the wrong Keyboard shows for a split second and then shows the proper Keyboard. By wrong keyboard I mean the Keyboard for an EditText with Input Type "Text".

I noticed, that I get this message in the Logcat:

```
D/Editor: setInputTypeforClipTray(): 0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

And sometimes:

```
D/Editor: hideClipTrayIfNeeded() TextView is focused!! hideClipTray()
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following into your `AndroidManifest.xml` under the corresponding `<activity>` block:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Solution found from [here](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/) in the comments.