# Numeric EditText shows Text keyboard momentarily (inactive InputConnection)

Tags: java, android, listview, logcat

I've been having this strange issue where clicking into an `EditText` within a `ListView` opens the numeric keyboard, then flashes a text keyboard, and then goes back to a numeric one. It doesn't happen again after, even when switching between other `EditText`. How can I keep the Text keyboard from showing?

Here is the relevant Debug Console output:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

Here is my `EditText` in `activity_main`:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_lot1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText_lot2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText_lot2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="7"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

What I've tried:

If I remove the `android:inputType`, then things work normally except now a SpellCheck error comes up, and the keyboard is obviously a text one.

I tried putting something in the `MainActivity` in my `onCreate()` such as

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I scoured the questions on here, and found [one similar case with no answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287173/recyclerview-with-edittext-worng-keyboard-for-a-split-second) Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution by putting the following into my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Under my corresponding `<activity>` block. Solution found from [here](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/) in the comments.